# XQuery - Enclosing sequence of elements under a single node

Tags: xquery, basex

I'm using xquery with BaseX to attempt to retrieve information from JMeter test cases (.jmx files) in a format I desire.
This is the code I'm actually running (inside BaseX GUI):

```
let $rlist := db:list("JMeter")
for $resource in $rlist
let $rcontent := db:open("JMeter", $resource)
let $ret :=
  <HttpRequest>
  {
    for $item in $rcontent/jmeterTestPlan//HTTPSamplerProxy
    return
      (<method>
      {
        $item/stringProp[attribute()/string() = "HTTPSampler.method"]/text()
      }
      </method>,
      <path>
      {
        let $parse := $item/stringProp[attribute()/string() = "HTTPSampler.path"]/text()
        let $parse := fn:replace($parse, "\?[^/]*", "")
        let $parse := fn:replace($parse, "\$[^/]*", "\${}")
        let $parse := fn:replace($parse, "[0-9]+", "\${}")
        return $parse
      }
      </path>,
      <resource>
      {
        $resource
      }
      </resource>)
  }
  </HttpRequest>

return
<HttpRequests>
{
  $ret
}
</HttpRequests>
```

The resulting xml looks like this:

```
<HttpRequests>
  <HttpRequest>
    <method>POST</method>
    <path>/config</path>
    <resource>CentralConfiguration/Requests/addConfiguration.jmx</resource>
  </HttpRequest>
</HttpRequests>
<HttpRequests>
  <HttpRequest>
    <method>POST</method>
    <path>/propertyType</path>
    <resource>CentralConfiguration/Requests/addPropertyType.jmx</resource>
  </HttpRequest>
</HttpRequests>
...
```

This is what I expect the result to look like:

```
<HttpRequests>
  <HttpRequest>
    <method>POST</method>
    <path>/config</path>
    <resource>CentralConfiguration/Requests/addConfiguration.jmx</resource>
  </HttpRequest>
  <HttpRequest>
    <method>POST</method>
    <path>/propertyType</path>
    <resource>CentralConfiguration/Requests/addPropertyType.jmx</resource>
  </HttpRequest>
  ...
</HttpRequests>
```

I'd much appreciate help in formatting my xquery to get the expected result, thanks

Comment: The example preceding your actual code is not helpful. Remove it and show the output you are getting with the actual code and the output you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by placing the outside for loop inside the first label.